# Error: spawn ENOENT - (Snapchat NPM) - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

When i launch my app's i have this error :

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
```

The NPM is : https://github.com/nykac/node-snapchat
And the example app i try to launch is "upload.js".

I think the problem is on the snapchat.js when i he load spawn :

```
spawn = require("child_process").spawn,
```

Thanks you.

Comment: `var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;`

`child = spawn('your command');`

then the **child** variable is become handler for your **child process**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
spawn = require("child_process").spawn,
```

And then :

```
var decrypt = spawn('openssl', ['enc', '-d', '-K', '4d3032636e5135314a69393776775434', '-aes-128-ecb']);
```

So you must have openSSL installed on your computer, and check if you have had it on your **PATH**